# TE Shrack miniature relay datasheet confusion

Tags: relay, footprint

This [relay](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data%20Sheet%7FPE%7F0919%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_PE_0919.pdf%7F1393219-3) (TE part number 1393219-3) datasheet has the following drawings in it (below). I am trying to make PCB footprint for it, and having issues with dimensioning.

Length = 20 mm max

Footprint length = 7*2.5 mm + 2*1.4mm = 20.3 mm

It appears that minimal length using footprint drawing is bigger than maximal length on the overall dimensioning drawing.

Second, relay's pins are rigid, and at the distance of 7*(2.54-2.5)=0.28 mm, and, per my experience, it may simply not insert properly. So where's the dimensioning slack here? No pin thickness in the datasheet.

Or maybe this document is NOT a datasheet, but marketing booklet?

[image]

[image]

**Update:** I put garbage information into registration window, and downloaded the .scr (script) file for EAGLE 6 (thanks @jsotola). First, why script as it (potentially) can be harmful? Next, created device is a sh*t.

Is it a modern trend not to make proper datasheet but forcing users downloading questionable files not being formal document, and rely on tools to properly executing the script?

[image]

[image]

And now I have to redraw this sh*t instead of creating thought device at once.

Comment: start here and follow the `digital datasheet link` ... there  are links to further info ... https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-7-1415539-4.html

Comment: I find none of them helpful. CAD files require me to register (thanks for not asking for upfront payment for the documents), 3D model is of no use.

Comment: the login screen has an option to `continue as a guest`

Comment: This looks like the typical sort of datasheet when companies have changed ownership a few times in recent years. Why not use a better part if that's the best they can do? I found a dubious source that shows the pins at 1.2mm (nominal? who knows?) which means the fit would be quite tight. It also omits the 2.50mm, showing only 2.54mm.

Comment: If you don't like the script files, then define your own components...

Comment: @SolarMike (alomst) always do this way using datasheets. Used available devices made by other people before, and decided that I would better spend a dozen minutes analyzing datasheet and drawing my own than rely on sometimes erroneous designs.